# How to prove this statement? (Real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

This might be the basic question in real analysis.

A function $f$   is $ C^2 $ function on the closed interval$ [0,1]$

Also the function $ f $ is satisfying $ f(0) = f(1) =0 $

Plus, $\vert f''(x) \vert  \le \  A $ on the open interval $(0,1)$

Show $\vert f'(x) \vert  \le \frac  A2 $  on the interval $(0,1]$

I tried many times through the Rolle's thm, Mean value thm etc.

But failed. Please give me some hints.

Comment: You should use a more explicit title which relates to the question.

Comment: Duplicate of [$f''$ bounded implies $f'$ is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/430461/721644), $$$$ [Proving that if $|f''(x)| \le A$ then $|f'(x)| \le A/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632850/721644), $$$$ [Question on functions and derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284443/721644), $$$$ [$f$ differentiable and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. , prove that $|f'(x)| \le \frac{A}{2}$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/912249/721644) $$$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two Taylor expansions at $x\in(0,1)$ are
\begin{eqnarray}
0&=&f(0)=f(x)+f'(x)(0-x)+\frac{f''(a)}{2}x^2,\\
0&=&f(1)=f(x)+f'(x)(1-x)+\frac{f''(b)}{2}(1-x)^2.
\end{eqnarray}
Here $a,b\in(0,1)$, hence $|f''(a)|\le A$ and $|f''(b)|\le A$. 
The second one minus the first one gives
$$
f'(x)=\frac{f''(a)}{2}x^2-\frac{f''(b)}{2}(1-x)^2.
$$
Now estimate
$$
|f'(x)|\le\frac{A}{2}(\underbrace{x^2+(1-x)^2}_{\le 1})\le\frac{A}{2}.
$$
The function $f'(x)$ is continuous, so the estimate can be extended to the closed interval.

Comment: I appreciate your amazing solution.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\int_0^xf'(t)dt=f(x)$

This means that

$\displaystyle\int_0^1f'(t)dt=0$

Assume that $f'(t)>A/2$ for some $a\in [0,1]$ and notice $f'(t)\geq f'(a)-Aa+At$ when $t<a$ and $f'(t)\geq f'(a)-At+Aa$ when $t\geq a$. Derive contradiction using the second integral.
A similar argument follows if $f'(t)<-A/2$ for some $a\in [0,1]$

Comment: I've never thought the solution using integral. Thank you.